# Auto Update Downloading Latest .exe file - how to verify it's not been tampered with?

Tags: c#, code-signing

We have a small console application (under 200kb) that will be distributed to clients and we want to ensure they run the latest version (verified by a WCF service). Currently it downloads the new .exe file over HTTPS and replaces the current .exe file with it.

Assuming our server isn't compromised, this would be ok. However we also sign our .exe file with a Code Signing certificate. Is there a way to verify this and delete the file if it doesn't match? We would need to be able to verify and delete the file without it ever being executed in case it is a virus.

How can we verify our signed .exe file? For example, Windows will show if it is invalid:
[image: Failed Digital Signature]

Edit: would this code do the job?

```
X509Certificate basicSigner = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(file);
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(basicSigner);
if (cert.Subject.Contains("CN=MY COMPANY NAME IN CERTIFICATE"))
    valid = true;
```

Edit: if we also check `StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx`, it comes back failed if one bit is changed in the file. Perhaps this is enough?

```
[DllImport("mscoree.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern bool StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(string wszFilePath, bool fForceVerification, ref bool pfWasVerified);
```

Edit: I've implemented this code too which calls **WinVerifyTrust** in **WinTrust.dll** to actually verify the Authenticode signature: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.winverifytrust

Now, it checks if the digital signature contains the correct subject, is from a valid trusted root, the signature is valid and if the code is strong named with it's digital signature. This must be safe enough now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/06/07/150378.aspx) is a nice walkthrough including source code on the options available to achieve what you want...

Basically you need to pinvoke [StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232579%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  since there is no managed API to do what you need.

Another option might be to [call SignTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388171%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that. I've edited the question to some code I have already. I presume this just checks the public value of the certificate - is this sufficient?

Comment: @IgorK that depends on what you want to achieve... your code basically checks the used cert but not the signature itself...

Comment: Seems if we check StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx it appears to reject modified files. I tried that example but it flew over my head to be honest!

Comment: @IgorK what sort of risk scenario are you trying to handle ? someone changing the exe on the server ? some virus changing the file client-side ?

Comment: Someone changing the exe on the server

Comment: @IgorK Then just create a checksum of the EXE (for example SHA-512) and verify it on download...

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Please see the latest edit. It now verifies the Authenticode signature using plug and play code. I presume this is safe now?

Comment: @IgorK "safe" is always relative in my experience... depending on how sophistated your attackers are that could be ok...

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty fundamentally wrong way to go about it.  The only thing that a code signing certificate proves is the identity of the person or company that signed the EXE.  The certificate authority merely proves that identity is valid.  What you haven't proved at all is that it is *your* certificate, you only proved that it is *somebody's* certificate.  An attacker could trivially replace your EXE with another one that was signed by him.

You'll probably object with "but can't I just verify it is mine!".  And the answer is no, if the attacker can replace the EXE then he'll have no trouble replacing your checking code either.  There is zero security in having the verification performed on the same machine.

Code certificates serve only one purpose, they prove the identity of the signer to the user.  Making them do anything else is a security hole.  The really bad kind, the kind that make you *feel* that your system is secure.  And make you stop thinking about implementing *real* security.

Comment: I prove it is my certificate if our company name is in a valid digital signature, granted by a CA. The attacker cannot replace the checking code... our app will already be at the client and is downloading a new version from our server, which we want to ensure has not been tampered with.

Comment: While I agree with what you said, authenticode is intended to address two issues: Authenticity and Integrity ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx#Ensuring_Integrity_a)).

Comment: @Hans Passant: The op said that an attacker can not replace the checking code. In this case, is it also the fundamental wrong way to go about? And why, how can this been attacked?